# How do I play a midi from the command line in Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, sound, music, midi

I'd like to do something like

```
$ play filename.mid
```

and hear the midi file played without opening up a graphical program.  Is there a package for Ubuntu that can do this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are many different packages/commands you can try:

1. `wildmidi` (as used by gstreamer)
2. `timidity` (found this very CPU intensive)
3. `playmidi` (never tried personally)

Comment: Do any of these work with sfz soundfont files? Or only with sf2?

Comment: wildmidi worked for me, Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 9):

You'll likely want the [`playmidi`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/playmidi.1.html) package (`sudo apt-get install playmidi`) which will allow you to play midi files from the command line.

`playmidi filename.mid`

Comment: Does `playmidi` work with `sfz`? It only seems to work for me with `sf2`.

Answer (score 6):

I know this thread is old, but I was looking for answers for a Raspberry Pi but didn't find any. After more work I came up with the following, it may work in Ubuntu too. The output is through a cheap USB to midi interface.

On Raspbian Jessie Lite with no extra installs:

```
pi@pizerow:~$ aconnect -l  
client 0: 'System' [type=kernel]  
0 'Timer           '  
1 'Announce        '  
client 14: 'Midi Through' [type=kernel]  
0 'Midi Through Port-0'  
client 20: 'CH345' [type=kernel]  
0 'CH345 MIDI 1    '  
pi@pizerow:~$ aplaymidi --port=20:0 myfile.mid
```

Comment: Helped me get where I needed to be! It's basic and doesn't offer many features, but it will indeed play the MIDI file once. fwiw, `aplaymidi -l` will also list the available MIDI ports. The relevant github is here if you want to improve the project: https://github.com/alsa-project/alsa-utils/commits/master/seq/aplaymidi

Answer (score 4):

`fluidsynth` from http://www.fluidsynth.org/.

Use it like this:
`fluidsynth /some/dir/with/sundfonts/some_soundfont.sf2 some.mid`

You can find soundfonts here: https://musescore.org/de/handbuch/soundfont

And quite a nice collection of MIDI files to try this out here: http://garyrog.50megs.com/midi1.html

I especially like the soundfont "Timbres of Heaven" from http://midkar.com/soundfonts/.

Comment: Does `fluidsynth` work with `sfz`? It only seems to work for me with `sf2`.

Comment: I'm a little late but Fluidsynth is written specifically to support the Soundfont format, which is sf2 and sf3. sfz is an entirely separate format.

Answer (score 1):

If you have fluidsynth installed, you can also play Midi files with VLC by installing the `vlc-plugin-fluidsynth` package.

Comment: The question asked 'without opening up a graphical program'. You don't say what the VLC command would be.  `cvlc <file>` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative besides Fluidsynth nowadays is Timidity. Install the packages `timidity`, `timidity-interfaces-extra` and `freepats` (the latter is about 30MB, but smaller than the sf2 files in `fluid-soundfont-gm`).  Then the following should work:

```
timidity -Os midi.mid
```